# Querying a nested JSON file in Python without Indexing

Tags: python, json

I have the below Json file which I need to query to get the values of the keys inside 'validations' in a list

for example the column_values_not_null output will need to be this:

`['lu_name', 'transaction_amount']`

```
  "validation_file_name": "ctm",
  "connection_type": "s3",
  "low_threshold": 500000,
  "high_threshold": 1000000,
  "frequency": "weekly",
  "validations": [
    {
       "columns_to_match_ordered_list" :[
        "lu_name",
        "site_name",
        "transaction_date_time",
        "margin",
        "transaction_currency_code",
        "reversal_indicator_description",
        "reversal_amount",
        "original_amount"
      ]
    },
    {
       "column_values_not_null":[
        "lu_name",
        "transaction_amount"
      ]
  },
    {
      "column_values_not_duplicate": [
         "lu_name",
        "response_code_description"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I am able to do the below but I need to do this without using the index value

```
f = open('test.json')

json_content = json.load(f)

print(json_content['validations'][1]['column_values_not_null'])
```

Comment: The value associated with `"validations"` is a list, so it can have many different objects. Do you know there will only be one with a `column_values_not_null` key? If there is more than one, do you want them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list by querying the validations key. The `sum( ,[])` are used to flat the list (as required by the condition *"without using the index value"* if got it right), for details about it with pros and cons see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

```
data = # 

def validations(data: dict, key_query: str) -> list:
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k == 'validations':
            return sum(sum([list(d.values()) for d in v if key_query in d], []), [])


print(validations(data, query='column_values_not_null'))

# ['lu_name', 'transaction_amount']
```